# Pull Rows Referencing A Formula

Tags: vba, excel, date, if-statement

I have a Macro to copy/paste rows if a cell in a specific column (Col H) has a value greater or equal than a given date --

```
Sub test30()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    If Range("H" & i).Value >= #1/1/2018# Then Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Next i
End Sub
```

This works fine, but instead of using **#1/1/2018#**, I want to reference a formula in cell B4 that pulls in the 1st day of the previous month (=EOMONTH(Today(),-2)+1).

I've tried replacing the date with "Cell B4", Range("B4"), .Cells(4,2) and nothing works. What am I missing?

Comment: `If Range("H" & i).Value >= Range("B4").Value ... ` did not work?

Comment: Exactly, try to use .value. Or alternatively, you can save date from range B4 to a date variable and use date functions for comparison (datediff(), or something similar).